# Using "should" with a negative meaning

Tags: grammar

I found this sentence in *Oxford Dictionary* in an entry for "draw up":

> Sarah drew herself up, full of indignation that he *should* presume to judge her.

Also this one in the entry for "sully":

> They were outraged that anyone *should* sully their good name.

My guess here is that "should" in the first example really means "should not", i.e, *he should not judge her* but I am not sure maybe some extreme meaning or pun is being used here beyond my pay grade in English grammar?

Comment: To simplify example #1: Sarah was indignant that he judged her. Not that he **did not** judge her, as we know he did. She *felt* he should not do it, but he did.

Comment: In this usage, _should_ can be (and usually is nowadays) replaced by _would_; the modals _shall_ and to a lesser extent _should_ are going moribund in American English.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a case of ***putative should***:

> In English grammar, *putative "should"* is the use of the word ***should*** in
> contexts that indicate ***surprise or disbelief***, or that refer to the
> *occurrence (or possible occurrence)* of some situation or event. This
> usage differs from the *should of obligation* (i.e., the mandative
> "should").
>
> As noted by Randolph Quirk et al., ***putative should (also called
> emotional "should")*** occurs in that clauses "***after expressions of
> emotion (sorrow, joy, displeasure, surprise, wonder, etc.)***, and is
> often accompanied by intensifying expressions such as *so, such, like
> this/that, ever, or at all"* (*A Comprehensive Grammar*, 1985)
>
> Also known as: *emotional should, attitudinal should, hypothetical
> should, subjunctive should* ([Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/putative-should-grammar-1691554))

Now, in your two examples the emotion is negative, not the ***should***, but you are right to understand that *in the mind of the person feeling that emotion the action of the verb following **should** should **not** occur*. Therefore, I wouldn't say that ***should*** bears the negative connotation in this case, but the emotion expressed before it.

Besides, *putative/emotional should* can be used in the negative:

> 'And me?' I said, ***outraged that he should not have included me.*** 
> (*[Girl With Green Eyes](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Girl_With_Green_Eyes/SHhHAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)*, Edna O'Brien 2013)

Comment: That's a very comprehensive, easy-to-understand explanation, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Khanh Note that even in the last example, the meaning in the mind of the speaker is still the opposite to what’s on the surface: “outraged that John should not have included me” means ‘outraged that John _didn’t_ include me’, in other words, the speaker feels that John _should_ have included them, but he didn’t. The speaker was outraged that John _failed to_ include them.

Comment: I just want to point out an error in the source - it's "should have" not "should of".

Comment: @nasch "Of" is actually correct here: what kind of _should_? _**Of** obligation_.

Comment: Of note, the putative should is not limited to relative clauses, but rather is allowed in any irrealis context. For example, the film _A Shot in the Dark_ includes a dialogue wherein a woman is accused of murdering a man "because you were having an affair with him!" Her reply: "I should kill him for that?"